# If $f(x, y)$ is continuous separately in $x$ and $y$, is it locally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

My hunch is that this is not true, but I haven't thought of a counterexample.

If not, is there another condition we can impose of $f$ to make it locally bounded (other than, of course, continuity)? Say, it is differentiable as a function of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(0,0)=0,$ $f(x,y) = xy/(x^4+y^4),$ $(x,y)\ne (0,0).$ Then $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2\{(0,0)\}),$ and $f$ is separately continuous at $(0,0).$  But $f(x,x) = x^2/(2x^4) = 1/(2x^2)$ for $x\ne 0,$ and this is unbounded in any neighborhood of $(0,0).$